# Bioconductor, RforProteomics, Installation error

Tags: r, bioconductor

## My system configuration

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_IN.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_IN.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_IN.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_IN.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_IN.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_IN.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_IN.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C 

  [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
```

### My Bioconductor Version

Bioconductor version 3.0 (BiocInstaller 1.16.1)

#### My problem

I want to intall RforProteomics which  I think have 75 dependencies! According to the authors instruction I did this biocLite("RforProteomics", dependecies =T)
This is showing error messages and installation can't be done. Which I understand is few of the dependencies not able installing and thus the error occurred.

### The error messages

```
rnetCDF.h:1:20: fatal error: netcdf.h: No such file or directory
 #include <netcdf.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [rnetCDF.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘mzR’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/mzR’
ERROR: dependency ‘mzR’ is not available for package ‘MSnbase’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/MSnbase’
ERROR: dependency ‘mzR’ is not available for package ‘xcms’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/xcms’
ERROR: dependency ‘mzR’ is not available for package ‘MSGFgui’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/MSGFgui’
ERROR: dependency ‘MSnbase’ is not available for package ‘synapter’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/synapter’
ERROR: dependency ‘MSnbase’ is not available for package ‘pRoloc’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/pRoloc’
ERROR: dependency ‘MSnbase’ is not available for package ‘pRolocdata’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/pRolocdata’
ERROR: dependencies ‘MSnbase’, ‘mzR’ are not available for package ‘MSnID’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/MSnID’
ERROR: dependency ‘MSnbase’ is not available for package ‘RforProteomics’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/RforProteomics’
Error in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) : 
  incomplete block on file

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpnro4j4/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

### What I did after this

I found rnetCDF is the one of the major component which is not installing or I don't have in my system and I did install.packages("RNetCDF") which showing another sets of error

### RNetCDF installation Errors

```
==================================================
downloaded 74 Kb

* installing *source* package ‘RNetCDF’ ...
** package ‘RNetCDF’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... gcc -m64 -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for nc_open in -lnetcdf... no
checking for nc_create in -lnetcdf... no
configure: error: netcdf library not found
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RNetCDF’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/RNetCDF’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpnro4j4/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("RNetCDF") :
  installation of package ‘RNetCDF’ had non-zero exit status
```

#### again I did install.pacakges("ncdf"). But this is also not installing.

## what should I do next?

please help me out

Comment: page 4 of `Using R and Bioconductor for Proteomics Data Analysis` says that external dependencies need to be installed first, with `mzR` one of the packages specifically mentioned. Did you try this?

Comment: Yes I tried that. Please see above I got error installing RnetCDF then I tried ncdf even that also not installing.

Comment: Yes I tried that. Please see above I mentioned the error installing RnetCDF then I tried ncdf even that also not installing.  Author mentioned libcdf which I don't know how to install.Please advice me . I am not a computer guy; please elaborate your suggestions a bit. thanks

Comment: I think you need to make the 'dev' version of the system library libnetcdf available, maybe along the lines of `sudo apt-get install libnetcdf-dev`. This might be partially misleading advice; you need the library, I'm just not sure whether libnetcdf is the right choice.

Comment: Since you are on red hat, follow [these instructions](http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=1429) (the Installing system libraries) section.

Comment: Thanks a lot  all of  you, those are spend their valuable time to solve my problem(specially Dan). It worked for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please quit R and install `libnetcdf-dev` by typing in terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libnetcdf-dev
```

(if using Ubuntu)